# Why docker is needed for Graphite installation

Tags: docker, graphite

I am trying to install graphite in my local system and monitor it using grafana. When I search for installing graphite, I find many installing docker with graphite. for ex. https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/monitoring/install-graphite-and-grafana/

Why do I need docker for installing Graphite

Comment: Just easy to install it I think, if you manually install it, there will be pain I guess.

Comment: Did you read the description, docker is required to "complete this guide", not that you cannot install Graphite at all without Docker. It's that with Docker it's super easy to install it, without Docker though it [can be](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-graphite-on-centos-7) a pain in the **s if you ask me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install with Docker. See https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id2 for other installation options.